# "Apply" "Cancel" buttons position

Tags: usability, gui-design, ios

I've noticed iStock iOS mobile app has unusual "Apply", "Cancel" buttons position. On my opinion if they were on the bottom usability of the search would be better as it would be easier to reach buttons with a thumb. Also it's kind of a common pattern to align them to the bottom. Do designers think "Reset all" is used more often? That's why it should be on the bottom and centered? But "Apply" is used the most often here so I would place it in the most comfortable position. What do you think?

[image: app screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is kind of a not-so intuitive UI.

But I don't think this is because of the *position* of the Cancel and Apply button.

Note that the particular screen shot of iStock is of a modal page. It slides up from the button if you tap on the "filter" bar. 
(Sidenote: it is kind of weird UX that you have to tap a down-arrow to make something slide UP from the bottom).

The standard UI for such a page on iOS would be to have a standard header bar at the top, with a Cancel button at the top left, and Save button at top right. So I don't find the positioning that odd.

See screenshot for standard positioning in Calendar App for adding a new appointment. Mail is similar.

[image: standard iOS UI]

However, these normally would be *inside* the black header bar, to the left and right of the title. 
Not directly below the header bar, as in the iStock app.

Answer (score 1):

"Reset all" should be used judiciously because if a user has made more than a few commitments it world be rare that they would want to clear all of these. And it looks like this is a filter, not a search.